# Mask R-CNN annotation tool

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I’m new to deep learning and I was reading some state of art papers and I found that mask r-cnn is utterly used in segmentation and classification of images. I would like to apply it to my MSc project but I got some questions that you may be able to answer. I apologize if this isn’t the right place to do it.
First, I would like to know what are the best strategy to get the annotations. It seems kind of labor intensive and I’m not understanding if there is any easy way. Following that, I want to know if you know any annotation tool for mask r-cnn that generates the binary masks that are manually done by the user.

I hope this can turn into a productive and informative thread so any suggestion, experience would be highly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use MASK-RCNN, I recommend it, is a two-stage    framework, first you can scan the image and generate areas likely    contain an object. And the second stage classifies the proposal    drawing bounding boxes.

> But the two-big question
>
> how to train a    model from scratch? And What happens when we want to
>   train our own    dataset?

You can use annotations downloaded from the internet, or you    can start creating your own annotations, this takes a lot of time!

You have tools like:

> VIA GGC image annotator
>   http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/via_demo.html

it's online and you    don't have to download any program. It is the one that I recommend you, save the images in a .json file, and so you can use the    class of ballons that comes by default in SAMPLES in the framework    MASK R-CNN, you would only have to put your json file and your images    and to train your dataset.

But there are always more options, you    have **labellimg** which is also used for annotation and is very well    known but save the files in xml, you will have to make a few changes    to your Class in python. You also have **labelme, labelbox**, etc.

Comment: if you have time, can you check if I am doing it correctly here:  https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1531?  Also, what do you mean, "class of ballons"?

Comment: I do not really understand exactly what you have done, about the Sample class, because it is easier to start, but you can start from scratch. Do you have your annotations yet? Can you specify your problem?

Comment: I see!  I just opened `balloon.py` and it has a bunch of commented code about using annotations from VGG Image Annotator.  I was looking here:  https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator because I thought I had to make annotations in COCO format but I guess not.

Comment: In my opinion the easiest way is to start using that file, creating your annotations using VIA GGC. It's easy to train on that, in your case the two classes, balls and background.

Comment: Let me know if you are bored to tears and want to annotate some tennis match frames.  Probably not right?

Comment: I'm not bored, you can attach your json file of an image to see if it's the right way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194292/discussion-between-mlstudent33-and-adonis-gonzalez).